# SQL Server Reporting Services Change report layout to Portrait

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Im writing a report with Reporting services that is almost always only going to be used as exported to PDF, but the PDFs i get are always in Landscape mode and i want them in Portrait (but only for this report)

Is there a way to change it between these pages layouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change my reports to landscape, I simply swap the "PageSize" property's Height and Width values on the report itself. If I make the width 29.7cm and the height 21cm, I get a landscape report. The other way around is portrait.

Reports are portrait by default though - if yours are showing up as landscape and nobody has changed the height and width of the page, then I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Dont know why i didnt think of that... Thanks!